# laravel response()->download return empty body for non-image formats like pdf, zip and so on

Tags: laravel

I want to download a file. File formats can be mp3, mp4, pdf, JPG, png and so on. The problem is that image format works properly and returns a correct file, but other file returns empty body and I can't download them.
My code is: (pdf format)

```
    $filePath = storage_path( 'messages/'. $message->message_file );

    if( file_exists($filePath) ){
      $headers = array(
          'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    );

    return response()->download($filePath, '', $headers);
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: does `$message->message_file` returns file name with file extension??

Comment: Yes, that's right. The problem was that IDM prevented from other formats (when send request from the app by axios). I don't understand anything but now it works :D